# Quickbooks and product options/variations - how should they be stored?

Tags: product, quickbooks, inventory-management

First - I'm not familiar with Quickbooks software, but I was asked to import products from the Quickbooks inventory to custom software.

My question is related to product options/variations manipulation under QB - are there specific fields for options/variations with their own SKU for each option/variation?

For example, there is XYZ candle which has size (burn time) options and each option has its own SKU. How should it be stored in QB in a proper way? How it will be indicated that XYZ candle has options and those options are related to XYZ candle?

Answer (score 0):

> are there specific fields for options/variations with own SKU for each option/variation?

No.

> How it should be stored in QB in a proper way? How it will be indicated that XYZ candle has options and those options are related to XYZ candle?

This is something *you should ask your client/accountant*. There is no single "proper" way - there are multiple ways to do this, and you should ask your client/accountant how they want to handle it in QuickBooks.

Some common scenarios are:

- multiple separate items
- parent/child items
- not doing it at all
- advanced inventory features of QB Enterprise

Comment: OK, so in a scenario where ecommerce software has no product and the client/accountant wants to import products from QB and some of those products have product options/variations and all is stored as multiple separate items simple there is no way for "automation" and splitting that between products, products with options and product options, until all was entered previously to ecommerce software and mapping products from there and QB using SKU as primary key for products, products with options and product options. Am I right?

Comment: Also what I found that there are "Custom Fields" in QB which can be used for the "primary product" definition when product options/variations are stored as multiple separate items. Can someone confirm that?